# Hibernate - PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find a getter for 

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a class that looks like the following:

```
public class MyClass {
    private String dPart1;

    public String getDPart1() {
        return dPart1;
    }

    public void setDPart1(String dPart1) {
        this.dPart1 = dPart1;
    }
}
```

My hibernate mapping file maps the property as follows:

```
<property name="dPart1" not-null="true"/>
```

I get the following error:

```
org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find a getter for dPart1 in class com.mypackage.MyClass
        at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor.createGetter(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:282)
        at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor.getGetter(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:275)
        at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.getGetter(Property.java:272)
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildPropertyGetter(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:247)
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.<init>(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:125)
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.<init>(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:55)
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityEntityModeToTuplizerMapping.<init>(EntityEntityModeToTuplizerMapping.java:56)
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:302)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:434)
        at
```

It appears that hibernate doesn't like my capitalization. How should I fix this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
<property name="DPart1" not-null="true"/>
```

should work...

Comment: I am also facing the problem and the above solutions works fine for me.
Now what I would like to know is is it java specification for setter getter methods or is it jboss specific implementation for hibernate?

Thank you for your answer :)

Comment: Could you please provide an explanation about your solution?

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 7):

for a property called "dPart1" a hibernate will try a getter named "getDpart1" not "getDPart1"
IIRC

Comment: the capitalization is important. i.e.

Comment: what if getDPart1 is required?

Answer (score 4):

Can't you just access it like a field?

access="field"

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution

Please make dPart1 to dpart1 and change the getter and setter again..

It is working for me now.

Remember to change the xml also.

Answer (score 0):

```
private String rptausu;

public String getRptausu() {
    return rptausu;
}

public void setRptausu(String rpta) {
    rptausu = rpta;
}
```

mapping:

```
        <property name="prtausu" />
```

works correctly

Answer (score 0):

From what I've seen, Hibernate (at least version 3.2.4) will expect a property like dPart to have a getter named getdPart: d stays lowercase. Look at dfa's answer as well - I am guessing that other versions might expect getDpart instead.

Answer (score 0):

The setter & getter should look like this

```
getdPart1()
setdPart1(....)
```

That's how the setters & getters are generated if generated through an IDE like eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

For a property
private Integer carId;

the setters and getters should be

getCarId() 
setCarId(Integer carId)

Answer (score 0):

The naming convention of the property matters example in my own case I initially used

```
private String newimsi, getNewImsi();
```

the above failed with same exception

> propertynotfoundexception

until I corrected to below before it worked

```
getNewimsi();
```

Answer (score 0):

Best Practice is not to create getters/setters by our self but use the Eclipse Shortcut(Alt+Shift+S) to create the same for the variables defined in a bean/pojo.

Naming convention does matters.