# " Could not find a getter for " Error

Tags: hibernate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hibernate - PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find a getter for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921239/hibernate-propertynotfoundexception-could-not-find-a-getter-for)

I am getting error when I am trying to run my code. Can you guys Please help. I have attached my mapping files. The issue here is that, am getting below error. " org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find a getter for eployeedetail in class bean.Employee "

Here is my Employee Class

```
   package bean;

   import bean.EployeeDetails;

   public class Employee {


    int             EmpId;
    String          name;
    String          phone;
    EployeeDetails          Edetails;

   public EployeeDetails getEdetails() {
        return Edetails;
    }
    public void setEdetails(EployeeDetails eDetails) {
        Edetails = eDetails;
    }
```

And other getters ans setters.

EployeeDetails.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
       "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
       "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

       <hibernate-mapping>
        <class name="bean.EployeeDetails" table="eployeedetail">
            <id name="EmpId">
                <column name="employee_id"/>
                <generator class="foreign" >
                <param name="property">eployee</param>
                </generator>
            </id>
            <one-to-one name="eployee" class="bean.Employee" constrained="true"></one-to-one>
            <property name="Address" column="ADDRESS"/>
        </class>
       </hibernate-mapping>
```

Employee.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
       "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
       "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

       <hibernate-mapping>
        <class name="bean.Employee" table="eployee">
            <id name="EmpId" column="employee_id">
                <generator class="native" />
            </id>
            <one-to-one name="eployeedetail" class="bean.EployeeDetails"/>
            <property name="name" column="NAME"/>
            <property name="phone" column="PHONE"/>
        </class>
       </hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: ` <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
       "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
       "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
       
       <hibernate-mapping>
        <class name="bean.Employee" table="eployee">
         <id name="EmpId" column="employee_id">
          <generator class="native" />
         </id>
         <one-to-one name="eployeedetail" class="bean.EployeeDetails"/>
         <property name="name" column="NAME"/>
         <property name="phone" column="PHONE"/>
        </class>
       </hibernate-mapping> `

Comment: You keep spelling "employee" wrong.

Comment: yes, By mistake I created my table as eployee instead Employee. so I maintained it.

Comment: edit your post & paste the code with proper formatting. it's horrible to read a mapping file in comments.

Comment: Sidenote: Have a look at Lombok to get rid of the need to write getters and setters manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `Employee.hbm.xml`. Whenever you specify a **one-to-one** tag, you need to specify 2 basic attributes:

1. **name** which represents name of the property. In you case it should be `Edetails` & not `eployeedetail`. **THIS IS THE REASON YOU'RE GETTING THE EXCEPTION.**
2. **class** which represents the class name which is associated as one-to-one with this class. In your case it should be `EployeeDetails`.

Change `Employee.hbm.xml`, change one-to-one tag attribute **name** to `Edetails` & your problem will be solved.

Comment: The description of the reason for the error is correct. But, the one-to-one doesn't have a column. one-to-one if not a many-to-one. It doesn't have a foreign key. It is based on linked primary keys or, bay using property-ref, linked foreign keys.

Comment: @StefanSteinegger, yes you're right. Thanks for pointing out. I've corrected the answer.

Comment: @Sri, If this answer is helpful to you you should accept it.

Answer (score 1):

change your code from

```
 EployeeDetails   Edetails;
```

this

```
 EployeeDetails    Edetails = new EployeeDetails();
```

Comment: Thanks Rajesh, But that dint help

EployeeDetails    edetails = new EployeeDetails();

public EployeeDetails getEdetails() {
  return edetails;
 }
 public void setEdetails(EployeeDetails edetails) {
  this.edetails = edetails;
 }

Can you please help

Comment: check property name used in hbm for EployeeDetails should be same as your object name.of course case sensitive

Comment: Yes Rajesh, It is same . I have attached my mapping file as a reply for @RAS

Comment: Is your object name is eployeedetail of EployeeDetails

Comment: Yes Rajesh, Now I got my error. As mentioned by RAS it was in Employee.hbm.xml. Thanks a lot for your help