# LookupField with one-to-many relationship

Tags: jpa, combobox, one-to-many, cuba-platform

I want to show in my document a one-to-many relationship- a simple drop-down list with values. For that, I trying to create and configure [`LookupField`](https://doc.cuba-platform.com/manual-6.7/gui_LookupField.html) component by using [Cuba platform](https://www.cuba-platform.com).

I have two entities:

CardItem:

```
@NamePattern("The document in the following state: %s|cardState")
@Table(name = "TKB_CARD_ITEM")
@Entity(name = "tkb$CardItem")
public class CardItem extends StandardEntity {

    // skipped
```

CardType:

```
@NamePattern("CardType: %s, %s |cardTypeItem, cardTypeName")
@Table(name = "TKB_CARD_TYPE")
@Entity(name = "tkb$CardType")
public class CardType extends StandardEntity {

    @OneToMany(targetEntity=CardItem.class )
    private List<CardItem> cardItems;

    // skipped
```

In my `card-item-edit.xml` I have the following:

```
<dsContext>
    <datasource id="CardItemDs" class="com.company.tkb.entity.CardItem" view="_local"/>
    <collectionDatasource id="CardTypeDs" class="com.company.tkb.entity.CardType" view="_local">
        <query>select c from tkb$CardType c</query>
    </collectionDatasource>
</dsContext>
<layout>
    <lookupField datasource="CardItemDs" property="cardTypeName" optionsDatasource="CardTypeDs"/>
```

I filled the table `TKB_CARD_TYPE` with some values. Now I'm trying to get a drop-down list with values when I create CardItem, but the list is empty.

What could be the problem?

I would be very grateful for the information. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What helped:

In `CardItemEdit` class I added the following:

```
public class CardItemEdit extends AbstractEditor<CardItem> {
    @Inject
    private Datasource<CardItem> cardItemDs;

    @Inject
    private Metadata metadata;

    @Override
    public void init(Map<String, Object> params) {
        CardItem cardItem = metadata.create(CardItem.class);
        cardItemDs.setItem(cardItem);
    }   
}
```

Then I changed the direction of the relationship: part of my `CardItem` entity:

```
@NamePattern("The document in the following state: %s|cardState")
@Table(name = "TKB_CARD_ITEM")
@Entity(name = "tkb$CardItem")
public class CardItem extends StandardEntity {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CARD_TYPE_ID")
    protected CardType cardType;

    // skipped
```

Part of my `CardType` entity:

```
@NamePattern("Тип входящего документа: %s | cardTypeName")
@Table(name = "TKB_CARD_TYPE")
@Entity(name = "tkb$CardType")
public class CardType extends StandardEntity {

    // skipped
```

I defined the `dsContext` and `lookupField` by this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<window xmlns="http://schemas.haulmont.com/cuba/window.xsd"
        caption="msg://editCaption"
        class="com.tkbbank.client.web.item.CardItemEdit"
        datasource="cardItemDs"
        focusComponent="fieldGroup"
        messagesPack="com.tkbbank.client.web.item">

     <dsContext>
        <datasource id="cardItemDs" class="com.tkbbank.client.entity.CardItem" allowCommit="false"/>
            <collectionDatasource id="cardTypeDs" class="com.tkbbank.client.entity.CardType" view="_local">
            <query>
                <![CDATA[select e from demo$CardType e]]>
            </query>
        </collectionDatasource>
    </dsContext>


    <dialogMode forceDialog="true" width="AUTO"/>
    <layout expand="windowActions" spacing="true">
        <fieldGroup id="fieldGroup" datasource="cardItemDs">
            <column width="500px">
                <field id="cardCreationDate" editable="false"/>
                <field id="cardType" caption="Тип документа">
                    <lookupField datasource="cardItemDs" property="cardType" optionsDatasource="cardTypeDs"/>
                </field>
                <field id="cardSubtype"/>
                <field id="cardAutoFill"/>
                <field id="cardOutcomeNumber"/>
                <field id="cardDate"/>
                <field id="cardOrganization"/>
                <field id="cardDeliveryMethod"/>
                <field id="cardAdditionalInformation"/>
                <field id="registratorName"/>
            </column>
        </fieldGroup>
        <frame id="windowActions" screen="editWindowActions"/>
    </layout>
</window>
```

What I see now. My card:

[image]

Interface for populating CardType with data:

[image]

Interface viewing all the documents:

[image]

Now everything is ok.

By side: very helpfull questions about "Can’t find getter for property" exception(this error is appeared also):

- [Hibernate - PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find a getter for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921239/hibernate-propertynotfoundexception-could-not-find-a-getter-for)
- [“ Could not find a getter for ” Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13471401/could-not-find-a-getter-for-error?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [What is the purpose of AccessType.FIELD, AccessType.PROPERTY and @Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13874528/what-is-the-purpose-of-accesstype-field-accesstype-property-and-access)
- [IllegalArgumentException: Can’t find getter for property ” at class…, and forgetting to update @NamePattern](https://www.cuba-platform.com/discuss/t/illegalargumentexception-cant-find-getter-for-property-at-class-and-forgetting-to-update-namepattern/4527)